# Why "no quarter" means "no mercy"?

Tags: meaning

As far as I know, "quarter" means half of half of something.

Why "no quarter" means "no mercy"?

Comment: You need to listen to this: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JJm8fZ6WS5Y

Comment: Close-vote #3 here. Words often have multiple meanings that you can look up in dictionaries, where they are glossed (and often traced to their origins) in multiple numbered definitions. [This site](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/) aggregates a number of good dictionaries. Do the research, and report back on it if you still have a question.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34308/origin-of-quarters-in-the-sense-of-living-area

Comment: I'm doing a research on this topic and it seems it's a very good question and a very good place to ask it, as etymology of the phrase is quite old, apparently, and nowhere to be found. I ended up here after extensive lookups and all I have is dictionaries which equate them as in the question, but it seems it's incorrect.

Comment: One theory states 'quarter' refers to customary "quarter of a yearly income of an officer" who was taken prisoner (notice nothing is said about ordinary soldier), and this amount was traditionally the amount of the ransom, and it's XVII century custom. However, the wording goes back to early XV century (most notably to Swiss Confederacy and their wars of independence), so possible it's translation from Latin word that lost it's original meaning. Same happened with 'auxiliary', which in Roman times (and even Machiavelli's) means something different than today (auxiliares).

Comment: 2/2 One thing is certain: Swiss usually gave "no quarter" before battle. This implies that yes, no prisoners will be taken, but you could always turn back before the fight. This is quite different from "no mercy", as that latter means "leave no one alive". Which would include wounded and non-combatants (camp followers).

Comment: I would add that as an answer, but question is closed. Vote to re-open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term arose from the military where the victorious side publicly proclaimed that it will not provide quarter (prison) for captured enemy. Which meant that no mercy will be shown and all prisoners will end up being slaughtered.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_quarter) has a  more elaborate description of the etymology:

> The term may originate from an order by the commander of a victorious army that they "will not quarter (house)" captured enemy combatants. Therefore, none can be taken prisoner and all enemy combatants must be killed.

- as well as an alternative etymology.

Comment: The quarter refers to military quarters, a dwelling place where troops can rest or be healed, a place where they were safe. In that sense, "no quarter" means no shelter for losers, i.e. death.

Comment: Can you link the Wikipedia article and include its essential part?

Comment: We find this particular use of the word in the Third Amendment: "No Soldier shall, in time of peace be **quartered** in any house, without the consent of the Owner, nor in time of war, but in a manner to be prescribed by law."

Comment: One theory states 'quarter' refers to customary "quarter of a yearly income of an officer" who was taken prisoner (notice nothing is said about ordinary soldier), and this amount was traditionally the amount of the ransom, and it's XVII century custom. However, the wording goes back to early XV century (most notably to Swiss Confederacy and their wars of independence), so possible it's translation from Latin word that lost it's original meaning. Same happened with 'auxiliares', which in Roman times (and even Machiavelli's) means something different than today.

Comment: 2/2 One thing is certain: Swiss usually gave "no quarter" before battle. This implies that yes, no prisoners will be taken, but you could always turn back before the fight. This is quite different from "no mercy", as that latter means "leave no one alive". Which would include wounded and non-combatants (camp followers).